# 'function' object has no attribute 'owner'

Tags: python, django

[error message 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm1UM.png)
[error message 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNqc6.png)

```
@login_required
def topic(request, topic_id):
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    _check_topic_owner(request)

    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic, "entries": entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)

def _check_topic_owner(request):
    if topic.owner != request.user:
        raise Http404
```

The problem is when im trying open page in web app. Is thow problem "'function' object has no attribute 'owner'"

Comment: The name `topic` in your second function refers to the first function, not to a variable in that function.  You need to pass the topic to be checked into the second function, as in `def _check_topic_owner( request, topic ):`.

Comment: Please do not post error messages as images, they should be [edit]ed into your question as code blocks. As well, you should make an attempt to debug these errors - if you `print(topic)`, what's the output? It's most definitely not going to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the name of the variable `topic` to a different name that doesn't clash with the function called topic.